# Baum Welch algorithm description

Tags: tabularx, booktabs

I am trying to replicate this table, on the Baum Welch algorithm, for Hidden Markov Models. I can not put expressions in the center, I'm trying with `\ begin {align *} ... \ end {align *}`, but the problem is that the vertical line is deleted. Somebody could help me?

**Expected Output:**

[image]

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \label{tabla4}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Algorithm 5:} The Baum-Welch algorithm \\ \midrule
        \textbf{Initialization:} \\
        \ $\Theta_0, \lbrace O_{1:T} \rbrace$  \\
        \\
        \textbf{Looping:} \\
        \textbf{for} $l = 1,..., l_{max}$ \textbf{do} \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ 1. Forward-Backward calculations:\\
        \ \ \vline \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ $\alpha_1 (i) = \pi_i b_i (O_1), \ \beta_T (i) = 1$, \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ $\alpha_t (i) = \left[ \sum_{j=1}^K \alpha_{t-1} (j) a_{ji} \right] b_j (O_t), \ \beta_t (i) = \sum_{j=1}^K a_{ij} b_j (O_{t+1}) \beta_{t+1} (j)$\\
        \ \ \vline \ \ for $1 \leq i \leq K, \ 1 \leq t \leq T-1$\\
        \ \ \vline \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ 2. E-step: \\
        \ \ \vline \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ $\gamma_t (i) = \frac{\alpha_t (i) \beta_t (i)}{\sum_{j=1}^K \alpha_t (j) \beta_t (j)}, \ \xi_t (i,j) = \frac{\alpha_t (i) a_{ij} b_j (O_{t+1}) \beta_{t+1}(j) }{\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_t(i) a_{ij} b_j (O_{t+1} \beta_t (j))}$ \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ for $1 \leq i \leq K, \ 1 \leq j \leq K, \ 1 \leq t \leq T-1$\\
        \ \ \vline \ \ \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ 3. M-step: \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ \\
        \ \ \vline \ \ $\pi_i = \frac{\gamma_1 (i)}{\sum_{j=1}^K \gamma_1(j)}, \ a_{ij} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \varepsilon_t (i,j)}{ \sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{t=1}^T \varepsilon_t (i, k)}, \ w_{kd} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \gamma_t (k, d)}{\sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{r=1}^D \gamma_t (k, r)}$\\
        \ \ \vline \ \ for $1 \leq i \leq K,\  1 \leq j \leq K, \ 1 \leq k \leq K, 1 \leq d \leq D$\\
        \textbf{end} \\
        \\
        \textbf{Result:} $\lbrace \Theta_l \rbrace^{l_{max}}_{l=0} $ \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You possibly want to use `algorithm2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,lined,shortend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\DataSty}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\SetKwData}[2]{%
  \algocf@newcommand{@#1}[1]{\DataSty{#2}: \ArgSty{##1}}%
  \algocf@newcommand{#1}{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\csname @#1\endcsname}{\DataSty{#2}\xspace}}%
  }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwData{Initialization}{Initialization}
\SetKwData{Looping}{Looping}
\SetKwData{Result}{Result}

\Initialization{$\Theta_0$, $\lbrace O_{1:T} \rbrace$}
\BlankLine
\Looping{}

\For{$l = 1,\dots, l_{\max}$}{
  1. Forward-Backward calculations:
  \begin{gather*}
  \alpha_1 (i) = \pi_i b_i (O_1), \ \beta_T (i) = 1, \\
  \alpha_t (i) = \Bigl[ \sum_{j=1}^K \alpha_{t-1} (j) a_{ji} \Bigr] b_j (O_t),
  \ \beta_t (i) = \sum_{j=1}^K a_{ij} b_j (O_{t+1}) \beta_{t+1} (j)\\
  \text{for }1 \leq i \leq K, \ 1 \leq t \leq T-1
  \end{gather*}
  2. E-step:
  \begin{gather*}
  \gamma_t (i) =
    \frac{\alpha_t (i) \beta_t (i)}{\sum_{j=1}^K \alpha_t (j) \beta_t (j)},
  \ \xi_t (i,j) =
    \frac{\alpha_t (i) a_{ij} b_j (O_{t+1}) \beta_{t+1}(j)}
         {\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_t(i) a_{ij} b_j (O_{t+1} \beta_t (j))} \\
  \text{for }1 \leq i \leq K, \ 1 \leq j \leq K, \ 1 \leq t \leq T-1
  \end{gather*}
  3. M-step:
  \begin{gather*}
  \pi_i = \frac{\gamma_1 (i)}{\sum_{j=1}^K \gamma_1(j)},
  \ a_{ij} =
    \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \varepsilon_t (i,j)}
    {\sum_{k=1}^K \sum_{t=1}^T \varepsilon_t (i, k)},
  \ w_{kd} =
    \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \gamma_t (k, d)}
         {\sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{r=1}^D \gamma_t (k, r)} \\
  \text{for }1 \leq i \leq K,\  1 \leq j \leq K, \ 1 \leq k \leq K, 1 \leq d \leq D
  \end{gather*}
}
\Result{$\lbrace \Theta_l \rbrace^{l_{\max}}_{l=0} $}

\caption{The Baum-Welch algorithm\label{baum-welch}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]